# Git ate my file

Tags: git, github

I am working on [a project on github](https://github.com/gbersac/lem_ipc_42). I have the file src/lem_in/src/player.c since 12 commit.

In the [last commit](https://github.com/gbersac/lem_ipc_42/commit/884b6308007f35f0d01146ba8a54c933dcda4829), I deleted a lot of file and push it to github. player.c disappeared. I may have deleted it by error so I checkout to a previous commit to restore it. It was gone there too ! And in every single commit. player.c has been deleted from the whole commit history without any reason !

I know it was there previously because my makefile still reference it and the compilation failed while I know the compilation always succeeded.

I know I didn't use strange git command (just git add, commit push).

How could this be possible ?

Comment: How did you revert to a previous commit?

Comment: The file might have existed, but not tracked by git.  It's very unlikely that git spontaneously rewrites the entire commit history to remove a file.

Comment: You probably never added it to git - so even though you had it locally (and compiled with it), you never told git to watch it. It might be in the recycle bin (or equivalent on your OS - as git usually soft-deletes the file when doing checkouts)

Comment: Here's your entire push history: https://api.github.com/repos/gbersac/lem_ipc_42/events?page=1.  There isn't a single force push in the history.  If the file would ever have existed in the git repository, it would still be there.  You deleted src/lem_ipc/src/get_player.c in [this commit](https://github.com/gbersac/lem_ipc_42/commit/b547b1749e38bdbe4ce99eaf858589b40f008e43) – Is this the file you are looking for?

Comment: @SvenMarnach no, it is still player.c

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is...I have `player*` in my .gitignore

I didnt' thought about checking it. My file is definitely deleted :(

Thanks for your answers.